# Flatlist does not support setting both, onViewableItemsChanged and viewabilityConfigCallbackPairs

Tags: javascript, react-native, flatlist

I have a flatlist like this:

```
      <AnimatedFlatList
        onViewableItemsChanged={({ viewableItems }) =>
          console.log("Data: " + JSON.stringify(viewableItems))
        }
        ref={scrollRef => {
          this.scrollRef = scrollRef;
        }}
        data={this.getDataSource()}
        contentContainerStyle={[
          !_.isEmpty(this.getPageActions())
            ? { paddingBottom: this.getScaledHeight(80) }
            : {},
          this.getContentContainerStyle(),
        ]}
        onScrollToIndexFailed={info => {
          const scrollView = this.getScrollViewNode(this.scrollRef);
          if (scrollView)
            scrollView.scrollToOffset({
              offset: info.averageItemLength * info.index,
              animated: true,
            });
          const wait = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 100));
          wait.then(() => {
            if (scrollView)
              scrollView.scrollToIndex({
                index: info.index,
                animated: true,
              });
          });
        }}
        onScroll={this._onScroll}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        removeClippedSubviews={false}
        ListHeaderComponent={this._renderListHeader}
        ListFooterComponent={this._renderListFooter}
        ItemSeparatorComponent={this._renderDivider}
        keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
        onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
        onEndReached={() => {
          if (this.paginationEnabled()) this.onEndReached();
        }}
        {...this.getlistProps()}
        renderItem={this._renderItem}
      />
```

I've setup onViewableItemsChanged, but upon app start, I keep getting the error:
**Flatlist does not support setting both, onViewableItemsChanged and viewabilityConfigCallbackPairs**

I don't see **viewabilityConfigCallbackPairs** being set. So cannot figure out what's the problem here. Could anyone help ?

Thanks in advance!